# Angular - cannot find module "ngx-thread"

Tags: angular, typescript, multithreading

I wanted to install the `ngx-thread` library for multithreading available here https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-thread. I typed `npm i ngx-thread` in the console to install it. When importing, I get a message from the compiler `Cannot find module 'ngx-thread'` . As in the picture below.:

[image: Cannot find module 'ngx-thread]

Surprisingly, the library is detected because the compiler tells me the path as I type.

[image]

The folder is also there.

[image]

And it's filled with files.

[image]

I tried to do typing npm install, npm uninstall, npm update, ng serve... In addition, I reset the project, cleaned the soultion, built it again and I still get this same error. I don't have such problems with other libraries.

Comment: Have you tried restarting the IDE? Do you get the same error if you try to build? It could just be due IDE or TS needing to pick up the latest from node_modules

Comment: I often have this issue when I install a new package or just add a new module to my app while the app is running (Using a second terminal). I just restart it and it works fine